# In python, how would I go about creating a save system for a text adventure?

Tags: python, text, save, system, adventure

Basically, a continue from left off system... kinda like any game has.
So far the idea I got going is to save the certain variables into a text file like name, health, xp, etc. and have a location variable that determines where the player is in the game and will act as the continue from left off.
Is there a simpler way about going about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving an Object (Data persistence in Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save all this information in some sort of object and pickle it. https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [json](http://json.org/) or [xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047318/easiest-way-to-persist-a-data-structure-to-a-file-in-python) question. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence-in-python?lq=1) one. Or just google [data persistence](https://www.google.cz/webhp?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=lrfIVYfDEoa6UZKRjIAE#safe=off&q=python%20data%20persistence).