# How can I write data to file in the python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code to create a user and login but the created user will be in memory only till the program is running and when the program closes then the user gets destroyed. Now if I decide to store the username and password to a file, then how can I do so in the below python code.I just want to store it to a file not to read or compare it yet. And I just started learning Python so don't know anything advance or any tricky terms.

Edit: I am unable to write the username and password to the file.

```
users = {}
status = ""

f = open('E:\\login_try2.txt','w')

def displayMenu():
    status = input("Are you registered user? y/n/q ")
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()
    elif status == "q":
        exitCode()

def exitCode():
    exit()

def newUser():
    username = input("Enter username: ")     
    f.write(username)

    if username in users:
        print("\nUsername already exists!\n")
    else:
        password = input("Create Password: ")
        users[username] = password
        f.write(password)
        print("\nUser created\n")

def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter username: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin Successful!\n")
    else:
        print("\nUser doesnt exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":
    displayMenu()

f.close()
```

Comment: What's the problem you are seeing with your code? A problem statement and a code dump is nice, but it doesn't show us where we can help clarify a specific issue.

Comment: I am unable to write the username and password to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047318/easiest-way-to-persist-a-data-structure-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: Getting any errors?

Comment: i am not getting any errors and the program is running fine

Comment: @tripleee I tried that but still the file's empty.

Comment: You should use `with open(filename) as f` instead of opening and closing the file manually. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. This might be the issue since your call to `f.close` never gets called

Comment: Tried what? The linked question has half a dozen answers, and your code doesn't implement any one of them.

Comment: if I use `import pickle` then `pickle.dump(variable, file_name)`, I get `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `f.close()` statement is only executed after exiting the application, so the data is not reliably flushed to the file.

Probably the easiest solution is to move `f.close()` to after `f.write(password)` in the `newUser` function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple. The `f.close()` was not getting called due to which the program was not able to store data in the file. So I added `f.close()` in the `def exitCode():`

```
def exitCode():
    f.close()
    exit()
```